# React return component onclick

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to return a component when I click on a button. 
(a delete button with a confirmation popup) I've tried some examples I found online but none really worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
class DeleteTask extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
        return <TaskDeleteModal />
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" className={styles.deletetask} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Verwijderen</button>;
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading, I hope you can assist me.

Answer (score 1):

It did not work because the `return <TaskDeleteModal />` of `handleClick` does not add `<TaskDeleteModal />` to your `render` function. 
You need to add `<TaskDeleteModal />` to render function and control it visibility by a state:
Try the following code:

```js
class DeleteTask extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  }
  handleClick() {
        this.setState({showModal: true})
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" className={styles.deletetask} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Verwijderen</button>;
            {/* In TaskDeleteModal you might have a button, when you click on that button call this.setState({showModal: false}) to hide the modal */}
         {this.state.showModal && <TaskDeleteModal />}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class DeleteTask extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  }
  handleClick() {
        this.setState({showModal: true})
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" className={styles.deletetask} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Verwijderen</button>;
            {/* In TaskDeleteModal you might have a button, when you click on that button call this.setState({showModal: false}) to hide the modal */}
         {this.state.showModal && <TaskDeleteModal />}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```